# address dynamically created label

Tags: python, kivy

I try to create a simple counting app.
I have buttons and labels, which are created via a for loop.
On_press of the button, the corresponding label should be updated with a new value (add one to the current number).

Here is the corresponding part of the .py file:

```
class ScreenCounter(Screen): 
    numberButtons = 0
    def on_enter(self):
        for i in range(len(birdname)):
            self.image = Image(source=birdimage[i])
            buttonName = 'bird'+str(i)
            self.button = Button(id=buttonName,text=birdname[i],on_press=self.onClick)
            labelName='birdCount'+str(i)
            self.label = Label(id=labelName, text='0')
            self.ids.grid.add_widget(self.image)
            self.ids.grid.add_widget(self.button)
            self.ids.grid.add_widget(self.label)
            self.numberButtons += 1

    def addCounter(self):
        layout = GridLayout(cols = 1, padding = 10) 

        self.popupLabel = TextInput(text = "", size_hint = [1, .7])
        saveButton = Button(text = "Speichern", size_hint = [1, .2])
        closeButton = Button(text = "Ende", size_hint = [1, .2]) 

        layout.add_widget(self.popupLabel) 
        layout.add_widget(saveButton)      
        layout.add_widget(closeButton)       

        popup = Popup(title ='Vogelname eingeben', 
                    content = layout,
                    size_hint = (0.7, 0.4),
                    pos_hint = {'center_x': 0.5,'center_y': 0.5})   
        popup.open()
        saveButton.bind(on_press = self.save, on_release = popup.dismiss)     
        closeButton.bind(on_press = popup.dismiss)

    def save(self, *args):
        buttonName = 'bird'+str(self.numberButtons)
        self.button = Button(id=buttonName,text=str(self.popupLabel.text),on_press=self.onClick)
        labelName='birdCount'+str(self.numberButtons)
        self.label = Label(id=labelName, text='0')
        self.ids.grid.add_widget(Label(text=''))
        self.ids.grid.add_widget(self.button)
        self.ids.grid.add_widget(self.label)
        self.numberButtons += 1

    def onClick(self, instance):
        print(int(instance.id[4:]))
        labelNumber = int(instance.id[4:])
        labelName = 'birdCount'+str(labelNumber)
        print(labelName)
        self.ids.grid.ids.labelName.text = 'new'
```

The .kv part looks like that:

```
<ScreenCounter>: 
    canvas.before:
        Color:
            rgba: 1, 1, 1, 0.3
        Rectangle:
            pos: self.pos
            size: self.size

    BoxLayout:
        orientation : 'vertical'
        Button: 
            id: newCounter
            text: "Neuer Zähler" 
            background_color : 1, 0, 0, 1 
            font_size: 80
            size_hint: 1, .1
            on_press:
                root.addCounter()

        GridLayout:
            orientation: 'horizontal'
            id: grid
            cols: 3
            spacing: 5
            padding: 5
```

The main problem is, that I can't change the text of the corresponding label, since I can't address it. It works if I try to address e.g. the button with the id "newCounter" but since the labels are created within the "grid" inside the GridLayout, it seems to fail. I get the following error:

```
 Traceback (most recent call last):
   File "kivy/properties.pyx", line 860, in kivy.properties.ObservableDict.__getattr__
 KeyError: 'labelName'
 
 During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:
 
 Traceback (most recent call last):
   File "/Users/jeff/python/birdcount/main.py", line 113, in <module>
     MyApp().run()
   File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/kivy/app.py", line 855, in run
     runTouchApp()
   File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/kivy/base.py", line 504, in runTouchApp
     EventLoop.window.mainloop()
   File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/kivy/core/window/window_sdl2.py", line 747, in mainloop
     self._mainloop()
   File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/kivy/core/window/window_sdl2.py", line 479, in _mainloop
     EventLoop.idle()
   File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/kivy/base.py", line 342, in idle
     self.dispatch_input()
   File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/kivy/base.py", line 327, in dispatch_input
     post_dispatch_input(*pop(0))
   File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/kivy/base.py", line 233, in post_dispatch_input
     listener.dispatch('on_motion', etype, me)
   File "kivy/_event.pyx", line 707, in kivy._event.EventDispatcher.dispatch
   File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/kivy/core/window/__init__.py", line 1402, in on_motion
     self.dispatch('on_touch_down', me)
   File "kivy/_event.pyx", line 707, in kivy._event.EventDispatcher.dispatch
   File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/kivy/core/window/__init__.py", line 1418, in on_touch_down
     if w.dispatch('on_touch_down', touch):
   File "kivy/_event.pyx", line 707, in kivy._event.EventDispatcher.dispatch
   File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/kivy/uix/screenmanager.py", line 1191, in on_touch_down
     return super(ScreenManager, self).on_touch_down(touch)
   File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/kivy/uix/widget.py", line 549, in on_touch_down
     if child.dispatch('on_touch_down', touch):
   File "kivy/_event.pyx", line 707, in kivy._event.EventDispatcher.dispatch
   File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/kivy/uix/relativelayout.py", line 288, in on_touch_down
     ret = super(RelativeLayout, self).on_touch_down(touch)
   File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/kivy/uix/widget.py", line 549, in on_touch_down
     if child.dispatch('on_touch_down', touch):
   File "kivy/_event.pyx", line 707, in kivy._event.EventDispatcher.dispatch
   File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/kivy/uix/widget.py", line 549, in on_touch_down
     if child.dispatch('on_touch_down', touch):
   File "kivy/_event.pyx", line 707, in kivy._event.EventDispatcher.dispatch
   File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/kivy/uix/widget.py", line 549, in on_touch_down
     if child.dispatch('on_touch_down', touch):
   File "kivy/_event.pyx", line 707, in kivy._event.EventDispatcher.dispatch
   File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/kivy/uix/behaviors/button.py", line 151, in on_touch_down
     self.dispatch('on_press')
   File "kivy/_event.pyx", line 703, in kivy._event.EventDispatcher.dispatch
   File "kivy/_event.pyx", line 1214, in kivy._event.EventObservers.dispatch
   File "kivy/_event.pyx", line 1138, in kivy._event.EventObservers._dispatch
   File "/Users/jeff/python/birdcount/main.py", line 84, in onClick
     self.ids.grid.ids.labelName.text = 'new'
   File "kivy/properties.pyx", line 863, in kivy.properties.ObservableDict.__getattr__
 AttributeError: 'super' object has no attribute '__getattr__'
```

This is my first post so I'm not sure if i provide all the needed information.
In addition, I'm new to kivy/python and this is my first "learning by doing" app, so if you have suggestions to improve the thing, I'm happy to read them.

Thanks for now!

EDIT:

Here is a working minimal example:

```
# bird_count - main.py
import kivy
import os
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.uix.screenmanager import ScreenManager, Screen, FadeTransition
from kivy.uix.button import Button
from kivy.uix.label import Label
from kivy.uix.gridlayout import GridLayout
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout

counterKV = Builder.load_file("counter.kv")
birdname = ['Amsel', 'Drossel','Buchfink']

class ScreenMain(Screen): 
    pass

class ScreenCounter(Screen): 
    numberButtons = 0
    def on_enter(self):
        for i in range(len(birdname)):
            buttonName = 'bird'+str(i)
            self.button = Button(id=buttonName,text=birdname[i],on_press=self.onClick)
            labelName='birdCount'+str(i)
            self.label = Label(id=labelName, text='0')
            self.ids.grid.add_widget(self.button)
            self.ids.grid.add_widget(self.label)
            self.numberButtons += 1
    
    def onClick(self, instance):
        pass
        # here, the corresponding label should add 1 whenever the button is pressed
        #self.ids.grid.ids.labelID.text = int(labelID.text)+1

class Manager(ScreenManager):
    pass

class MyApp(App):
    def build(self):
       return Manager()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    MyApp().run()
```

.kv:

## : import sm kivy.uix.screenmanager

```
<Manager>:
    ScreenMain:
        name: 'ScreenMain'
    ScreenCounter:
        name: 'ScreenCounter'


<ScreenMain>: 

    BoxLayout: 
        Button: 
            text: "Neue Zählung" 
            background_color : 0.12, 0.42, 0.23, 1  
            on_press: 
                root.manager.transition.direction = 'left' 
                root.manager.transition.duration = 0.3
                root.manager.current = 'ScreenCounter'
      
<ScreenCounter>: 

    BoxLayout:
        GridLayout:
            orientation: 'horizontal'
            id: grid
            cols: 3
            spacing: 5
            padding: 5
```

I can't remove the first screen or I run into a different error :-|

Comment: Can you provide a minimal runnable example?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `ids` dictionary is created when a `kv` file/string is loaded. Any `id` that you create outside of `kv` is just an attribute of a `Widget`, and will not be in the `ids`. So, you need create a way for yourself to maintain references to your labels. An easy way is to just keep a list of them. Here is a modified version of your `ScreenCounter` class (from your `mcve`), that I think does what you want:

```
class ScreenCounter(Screen):
    numberButtons = 0

    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(ScreenCounter, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        self.labels = []    # create a list of labels

    def on_enter(self):
        for i in range(len(birdname)):
            buttonName = 'bird'+str(i)
            self.button = Button(id=buttonName,text=birdname[i],on_press=self.onClick)
            labelName='birdCount'+str(i)
            self.label = Label(id=labelName, text='0')
            self.labels.append(self.label)     # add this label to the list of labels
            self.ids.grid.add_widget(self.button)
            self.ids.grid.add_widget(self.label)
            self.numberButtons += 1

    def onClick(self, instance):
        labelNumber = int(instance.id[4:])

        # Access the label via the list
        self.labels[labelNumber].text = str(int(self.labels[labelNumber].text) + 1)
```

Another possibility, is to create your own `id` dictionary. Here is another version of `ScreenCounter` using a dictionary named `myIds`:

```
class ScreenCounter(Screen):
    numberButtons = 0

    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(ScreenCounter, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        self.myIds = {}    # create a dictionary of labels

    def on_enter(self):
        for i in range(len(birdname)):
            buttonName = 'bird'+str(i)
            self.button = Button(id=buttonName,text=birdname[i],on_press=self.onClick)
            labelName='birdCount'+str(i)
            self.label = Label(id=labelName, text='0')
            self.myIds[labelName] = self.label    # add this label to the myIds dictionary
            self.ids.grid.add_widget(self.button)
            self.ids.grid.add_widget(self.label)
            self.numberButtons += 1

    def onClick(self, instance):
        labelNumber = int(instance.id[4:])
        labelName = 'birdCount'+str(labelNumber)

        # Access the label via myIds
        self.myIds[labelName].text = str(int(self.myIds[labelName].text) + 1)
```